# Linux+Gnome: can't bind shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+Esc

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, gnome

I am using arch Linux with gnome 3.26.2 and x11.

In previous versions of gnome I could use gnome's settings to assign a shortcut to 
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, but not anymore.

`xev` prints the lines below when hitting this combo:

```
FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
```

`showkey -a` does not print anything when hitting this combination.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/549111) help ?

Comment: I am using arch+gnome shell (and not unity) I don't see how and why ccsm is relevant.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018814/custom-shortcut-ctrl-shift-esc-doesnt-fire-the-event